# Как экспортировать данные взятые из asyncstorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, expo

Я пишу приложение на react native с использованием [expo](https://expo.io), а для навигации использую [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/). Когда человек регистрируется или входит в аккаунт, я сохраняю данные в [asyncstorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#docsNav). Позже при запуске приложения данные должны доставаться из [asyncstorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#docsNav). И от них зависит какая будет начальная страница меню или приветствие, но [asyncstorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#docsNav) асинхронен в отличие от экспорта который может быть только синхронен. Как я могу решить данную ситуацию, или же реализовать сохранение входа в аккаунт как-то по другому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Показать экран загрузки
2. Подождать ответ asyncstorage
3. Показать экран зарегистрированного пользователя или экран авторизации